# Text color looks normal until i render it

Tags: rendering, texturing

[image][image: enter image description here][1]]The text of my intro had a normal color until i rendered it. The color was all of sudden darker than usual.

Comment: hi please provide more details, add some screenshots or upload the blend file

Comment: if you know how to fix it pls help me

Comment: well there should still be more information in the question . search for "Final render looks different than preview" see if you find a solution. also look at questions and what screenshots and details you should add

Comment: sorry im using this wbsite the first time i dont really know what should i type and add

Comment: its ok take your time. in blender there are some options for previewing the scene . look at the top right corner you see 4 little spheres final render is closest to the last one . from left to right hover over them you see wireframe , solid , material , render , if material and final render are different its because if lighting you need more lights

Comment: Hello and welcome. Did you add lights to your scene?

Comment: @mma78 how do i add more lights? im pretty new at blender, and what do you recommend to be the file format.

Comment: press Shift +  A and from light category select a sun or something ot you can go to to world properties in properties editor usualy at the right of the window and change the entire scene color to a lighter value

Comment: yessss finally thank you so much man i appreciate it <3